# SImple search function in YDN-DB

Tags: javascript, ydn-db

I'm trying to make a simple function that allows me to search a specific item inside a specific table and return the desired results using YDN-DB, so far I have this:

```
var simpleSearch = function(table,field,string,limit,callback){ 
    var look = db.from(table).where(field, '=', string).list(limit);
    look.done(function(result) {
        callback(true,result);
    });
    look.fail(function() {
        callback(false,'');
    });
}
//usage
simpleSearch('mytable','fieldname','nice field',1,function(found,result){
  if(found){
    console.log('item '+result.fieldname+' found'); //on success should output 'item nice field found'
  }else{
   console.log('nothing found');
  }
});
```

Now the thing is, this code isn't working at all. Can you please help me or point me out where am I wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I think I found the solution:

```
var simpleSearch = function(table,field,operator,string,limit,callback){    
    var look = db.from(table).where(field, operator, string).list(limit);
    look.done(function(result){
        if(result.length > 0){
            console.log('search found');
            callback(true,result);
        }else{
            console.log('search not found');
            callback(false,'');
        }
    });
}

//usage

simpleSearch('users','id','=',userId,1,function(found,result){
            if(found){
                console.log(result.name);
            }else{
                //user wasn't found, do something about it
            }
        });
```

Make sure to add in your schema the field you want to search as `keypath`. 
If someone can improve this answer, please don't doubt about posting it here.